# How do I fix a 3D ACII .ply that is registering as an atmoic vector in the RStudios Geomorph package?

Tags: r, 3d, morphological-analysis

When I try to place landmarks on my 3D model, after opening it and placing it into the RStudios Global Environment, I get "Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors". Before this step, I am able to plot the object successfully in a data frame. I also get this problem when I try to change the color using the $material as well as the [material] command. Is there some kind of conversion process that I need to do before-hand to convert the file into a Data Frame or into an Array?

I do not have much experience with the package so I have tried reexporting the original binary .ply as an ACII .ply from both MeshLab and Rhino to no avail.

> library("geomorph", lib.loc="~/R/win-library/3.5")
>
> read.ply("...")
>
> BI98<-read.ply("...")
>
> digit.fixed(..., 10,,ptsize = .1)
>
> Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

For color:

> ...$material<-"gray"
>
> Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
>
> ...[material]<-"gray"
>
> Error: $ operator is invalid for atmoic vectors

At the very least I would like to have the ability to place landmarks even if I am not able to change the color of the object.

Answer (score 0):

I think that if you use the Environment menu panel's "Import Dataset" tool (click the icon), select "From text (base)..", then select your ASCII ply file. Then, in the "Separator" field, use the drop-down menu and select "Comma". The default is "Whitespace". After you change "Whitespace"->"Comma", you should see a repopulation of characters in the preview panel. Proceed with the import. It might work but there could be another issue.